# Передача mp3 файла через сокет

Tags: java

Пишу программу для передачи mp3 файлов по сокету. Смог передать строчку от сервера к клиенту. Перечитал форумы и туториалы, но везде все обрывками и подводные камни, из за чего не понятно. Помоги переписать код так, что бы можно было передать файл. Выкладываю добрую половину кода с комментариями, что бы было понятно как я все устроил.

сервер

```
Thread myThready = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() //Этот метод будет выполняться в побочном потоке
    {
        System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");

        try {

            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port); // создаем сокет сервера и привязываем его к вышеуказанному порту
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client...");

            Socket socket = ss.accept(); // заставляем сервер ждать подключений и выводим сообщение когда кто-то связался с сервером
            System.out.println("Got a client :) ... Finally, someone saw me through all the cover!");
            System.out.println();

            // Берем входной и выходной потоки сокета, теперь можем получать и отсылать данные клиенту.
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();






            // Конвертируем потоки в другой тип, чтоб легче обрабатывать текстовые сообщения.
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            String line = null;
            while (true) {
                line = in.readUTF(); // ожидаем пока клиент пришлет строку текста.
                System.out.println("Клиент прислал мне: " + line);
                System.out.println("Я возвращаю её обатно...");
                out.writeUTF(line); // отсылаем клиенту обратно ту самую строку текста.
                out.flush(); // заставляем поток закончить передачу данных.
                System.out.println("Ожидание...");
                System.out.println();

            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
});
```

Клиент

```
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Привет из побочного потока!");

        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address); // создаем объект который отображает вышеописанный IP-адрес.
            System.out.println("Any of you heard of a socket with IP address " + address + " and port " + serverPort + "?");
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort); // создаем сокет используя IP-адрес и порт сервера.
            System.out.println("Yes! I just got hold of the program.");

            // Берем входной и выходной потоки сокета, теперь можем получать и отсылать данные клиентом.
            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            // Конвертируем потоки в другой тип, чтоб легче обрабатывать текстовые сообщения.
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);




            // Создаем поток для чтения с клавиатуры.
            BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("Type in something and press enter. Will send it to the server and tell ya what it thinks.");
            System.out.println();

            while (true) {
                line = keyboard.readLine(); // ждем пока пользователь введет что-то и нажмет кнопку Enter.
                System.out.println("Отпрака строки серверу...");
                System.out.println();
                out.writeUTF(line); // отсылаем введенную строку текста серверу.
                out.flush(); // заставляем поток закончить передачу данных.
                line = in.readUTF(); // ждем пока сервер отошлет строку текста.
                System.out.println("Сервер прислал мне : " + line);
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: так и что у вас конкретно не получается?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Я смог передать строку, но не понимаю как написать код для передачи файла.

Comment: а чем строка от файла отличается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таких случаях нужно читать данные в байт массив.

```java
BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

if (input.available() > 0)
{
    int bSize = input.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bSize];
    input.read(buffer);
}
```

Да и общение с клиент <-> сервер нужно делать не String, а через Byte константы. Например опкодами. По опкоду опрелелять что присылвется - файл или текст. И соответственно разбирать входящие данные по соответствующему шаблону.

Посмотрите в сторону MMOCore для Java серверов Lineage 2 и Minecraft. Там есть готовая реализация обмена данными.